# Add Jmeter APDEX OK and KO columns

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am using Jmeter version-5. After the load test is complete am using APDEX to generate reports. And inside this JMETER APDEX report, i am seeing samples, ok, Error etc. So, how can i add OK column additionally in APDEX report of JMETER v5?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename `Apdex` column to `OK` it's very easy, just add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
reportgenerator_summary_apdex_apdex=OK
```

and next time you will generate the dashboard, the `Apdex` column will be renamed to `OK`

More information:

- JMeter Properties Reference
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

If you want to add a brand new column `OK` which will be true or false depending on the frustration threshold you will need to:

1. Declare its name in [AbstractSummaryConsumer#createResultTitles function](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/report/processor/ApdexSummaryConsumer.java#L157)
2. Implement the desired behaviour in [AbstractSummaryConsumer.createDataResult](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/report/processor/ApdexSummaryConsumer.java#L55) function
3. Add the new column in [dashboard.js.fmkr](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/report-template/content/js/dashboard.js.fmkr#L176)
4. [Rebuild JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html)